# how to delete many documents from firebase using where condition

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

how to delete many documents from firebase using where condition

I have two collections issues and orders and i want to delete issues where its orderID is equal to `orderID`

```
issuesCollection.where('orderID', isEqualTo: orderID).snapshots().foreach((f){f.delete()})
```

Comment: Firestore does not have an operation to delete with a condition.  You have to query for the matching documents, iterate them, and delete them invidually.

Comment: but the answer in the question that they mention is not working! can u help me

Comment: If you have code that isn't working the way you expect, post a new question with that code and explain the problem with it in detail.

Comment: As far as I can see your `f` variable is a `DocumentSnapshot` which doesn't have a `delete()` method. What you'll want is `f.reference.delete()`.